# How to change LINQ to SQL connection string dynamically at runtime and store in Project Settings?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, configuration

I want to create a custom config screen so that I can modify the LINQ database connection at runtime. Apart from changing the app.config which would then require me to restart the software, is there anyway I can change the LINQ database connection string at runtime? And store this in the Project's Settings?

Comment: LINQ doesn't have a database connection. You probably mean Linq-to-sql or Entity Framework.

Comment: Duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019434/how-can-i-make-linq-to-sql-use-a-connection-string-which-is-being-modified-at-ru

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use in my project. It's static so can be called anywhere. Change MyEntities and MyModel for the appropriate names for your project.

```
    public static MyEntities NewContext()
    {
        var y = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        y.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        string conn = CodeToGetConnectionStringHere();
        if(!conn.EndsWith(";")) conn += ";";
        conn += "MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        y.ProviderConnectionString = conn;
        y.Metadata = "res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl";
        return new MyEntities(y.ConnectionString);
    }
```

Comment: I haven't used linq to sql so cannot answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely store your connection string in project settings; and build it using [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336613%28v=vs.90%29) class.

```
class ConnectionStringFactory
{
    internal stati string BuildModelConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            Metadata = @"your metadata string",
            ProviderConnectionString = connectionString
        };
        return builder.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

You can then use the method from above in your code like this:

```
var connectionString = ConnectionStringFactory.BuildModelConnectionString(Settings.ConnectionString);
using(var dataContext = new DataContext(connectionString))
{
    // your logic here...
}
```